# Python concatenating elements of one list that are between elements of another list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have two lists: `a` and `b`.  I want to concatenate all of the elements of the `b` that are between elements of `a`. All of the elements of `a` are in `b`, but `b` also has some extra elements that are extraneous. I would like to take the first instance of every element of `a` in `b` and concatenate it with the extraneous elements that follow it in `b` until we find another element of `a` in `b`. The following example should make it more clear.

```
a = [[11.0, 1.0], [11.0, 2.0], [11.0, 3.0], [11.0, 4.0], [11.0, 5.0], [12.0, 1.0], [12.0, 2.0], [12.0, 3.0], [12.0, 4.0], [12.0, 5.0], [12.0, 6.0], [12.0, 7.0], [12.0, 8.0], [12.0, 9.0], [12.0, 10.0], [12.0, 11.0], [12.0, 12.0], [12.0, 13.0], [12.0, 14.0], [13.0, 1.0], [13.0, 2.0], [13.0, 3.0], [13.0, 4.0], [13.0, 5.0], [13.0, 6.0], [13.0, 7.0], [13.0, 8.0], [13.0, 9.0], [13.0, 10.0]]  

b = [[11.0, 1.0], [11.0, 1.0], [1281.0, 8.0], [11.0, 2.0], [11.0, 3.0], [11.0, 3.0], [11.0, 4.0], [11.0, 5.0], [12.0, 1.0], [12.0, 2.0], [12.0, 3.0], [12.0, 4.0], [12.0, 5.0], [12.0, 6.0], [12.0, 7.0], [12.0, 5.0], [12.0, 8.0], [12.0, 9.0], [12.0, 10.0], [13.0, 5.0], [12.0, 11.0], [12.0, 8.0], [3.0, 1.0], [13.0, 1.0], [9.0, 7.0], [12.0, 12.0], [12.0, 13.0], [12.0, 14.0], [13.0, 1.0], [13.0, 2.0], [11.0, 3.0], [13.0, 3.0], [13.0, 4.0], [13.0, 5.0], [13.0, 5.0], [13.0, 5.0], [13.0, 6.0], [13.0, 7.0], [13.0, 7.0], [13.0, 8.0], [13.0, 9.0], [13.0, 10.0]]

c = [[[11.0, 1.0], [11.0, 1.0], [1281.0, 8.0]], [[11.0, 2.0]], [[11.0, 3.0], [11.0, 3.0]], [[11.0, 4.0]], [[11.0, 5.0]], [[12.0, 1.0]], [[12.0, 2.0]], [[12.0, 3.0]], [[12.0, 4.0]], [[12.0, 5.0]], [[12.0, 6.0]], [[12.0, 7.0], [12.0, 5.0]], [[12.0, 8.0]], [[12.0, 9.0]], [[12.0, 10.0], [13.0, 5.0]], [[12.0, 11.0], [12.0, 8.0], [3.0, 1.0]], [[13.0, 1.0], [9.0, 7.0], [12.0, 12.0], [12.0, 13.0], [12.0, 14.0], [13.0, 1.0]], [[13.0, 2.0]], [[11.0, 3.0], [13.0, 3.0]], [[13.0, 4.0]], [[13.0, 5.0], [13.0, 5.0], [13.0, 5.0]], [[13.0, 6.0]], [[13.0, 7.0], [13.0, 7.0]], [[13.0, 8.0]], [[13.0, 9.0]], [[13.0, 10.0]]]
```

What I have thought of is something like this:

```
slice_list = []
for i, elem in enumerate(a):
    if i < len(key_list)-1:
        b_first_index = b.index(a[i])
        b_second_index = b.index(a[i+1]) 
        slice_list.append([b_first_index, b_second_index])

c = [[b[slice_list[i][0]:b[slice_list[i][1]]]] for i in range(len(slice_list))]
```

This however will not catch the last item in the list (which I am not quite sure how to fit into my list comprehension anyways) and it seems quite ugly. My question is, is there a neater way of doing this (perhaps in itertools)?

Comment: I am having a very hard time understanding your desired end-state, but I suspect there is a much simper/cleaner way to do this using sets instead of lists. Are you saying you want a list of lists, each one starting with the first index of a key_list and containing "extraneous" lists? What do you want to keep, and what do you want to get rid of?

Comment: Yes, it is kind of a complicated question. The wrong_list is basically the key_list with a bunch of extraneous items. I would like wrong_list to be fixed using the elements of key_list so that the first element of each element in list of lists wrong_list_fixed is an element of key_list. Basically I want to group all the extraneous info between the elements of key_list

Comment: @sfortney Side note: I think you should consider using different abstractions in your example.  I'm having a very tough time wrapping my head around `key_list` and `wrong_list`.  Maybe `a` and `b` would be better :)

Comment: Also, I don't see a nicer way to get the desired output than a list of lists (I am happy to be wrong about that though)

Comment: @alex I will edit it

Comment: So you want something like: [[(11.0, 1.0),(1281.0, 8.0)], [(11.0, 2.0),(more extraneous)]]? Also, what is the value of having duplicates in your wrong_list?

Comment: Exactly. Just like in the example. I would prefer there to not be the duplicates but they are necessary because each one represents a string and I am going to concatenate all of the strings in the list of lists

Comment: The application in mind is text parsing if that helps. These are the titles of strings and I need to concatenate the strings where the titles don't match up to the key_list (or b in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example wrong_list_fixed is incorrect.

```
        [[12.0, 10.0], [13.0, 5.0], [12.0, 11.0], [12.0, 8.0],
# There should be a new list here -^
```

Here's a solution that walks the lists. It can be optimized further:

```
from contextlib import suppress

fixed = []
current = []
key_list_iter = iter(key_list)
next_key = next(key_list_iter)
for wrong in wrong_list:
    if wrong == next_key:
        if current:
            fixed.append(current)
            current = []
        next_key = None
        with suppress(StopIteration):
            next_key = next(key_list_iter)
    current.append(wrong)

if current:
    fixed.append(current)
```

Here are the correct lists (modified to be easier to visually parse):

```
key_list = ['_a0', '_b0', '_c0', '_d0', '_e0', '_f0', '_g0', '_h0', '_i0', '_j0', '_k0', '_l0', '_m0', '_n0', '_o0', '_p0', '_q0', '_r0', '_s0', '_t0', '_u0', '_v0', '_w0', '_x0', '_y0', '_z0', '_A0', '_B0', '_C0'] 
wrong_list = ['_a0', '_a0', 'D0', '_b0', '_c0', '_c0', '_d0', '_e0', '_f0', '_g0', '_h0', '_i0', '_j0', '_k0', '_l0', '_j0', '_m0', '_n0', '_o0', '_x0', '_p0', '_m0', 'E0', '_t0', 'F0', '_q0', '_r0', '_s0', '_t0', '_u0', '_c0', '_v0', '_w0', '_x0', '_x0', '_x0', '_y0', '_z0', '_z0', '_A0', '_B0', '_C0'] 
wrong_list_fixed = [['_a0', '_a0', 'D0'], ['_b0'], ['_c0', '_c0'], ['_d0'], ['_e0'], ['_f0'], ['_g0'], ['_h0'], ['_i0'], ['_j0'], ['_k0'], ['_l0', '_j0'], ['_m0'], ['_n0'], ['_o0', '_x0'], ['_p0', '_m0', 'E0', '_t0', 'F0'], ['_q0'], ['_r0'], ['_s0'], ['_t0'], ['_u0', '_c0'], ['_v0'], ['_w0'], ['_x0', '_x0', '_x0'], ['_y0'], ['_z0', '_z0'], ['_A0'], ['_B0'], ['_C0']]
```

Comment: That's possible. I made the desired output by hand. Testing it right now.

Comment: I like this one the best and this is what I ended up using. Mad Physicist's answer was great too though. This one just came in first and seems a bit more maintainable in general. Speed isn't as big a concern as maintainability in this problem.

Comment: Edited my Q to fix the desired output. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

Let's simplify the visual a bit:

```
key_list = ['a', 'c', 'f']
wrong_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
wrong_list_fixed = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']]
```

This will be semantically identical to what you have, but I think it is easier to see without all the extra nested brackets.

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), if you could only come up with a clever key. Luckily, the mapping of `key_list` to `wrong_list` givs you exactly what you want:

```
class key:
    def __init__(self, key_list):
        self.last = -1
        self.key_list = key_list
    def __call__(self, item):
        try:
            self.last = self.key_list.index(item, self.last + 1)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return self.last
wrong_list_fixed = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(wrong_list, key(key_list))]
```

The key maps elements of `wrong_list` to `key_list` using [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). For missing indices, it just returns the last one successfully found, ensuring that groups are not split until a new index is found. By starting the search from the next available index, you can ensure that duplicate entries in `key_list` get handled correctly.

[[IDEOne Link]](https://ideone.com/jXwiGs)

Comment: In your `ValueError` case, it will be immediately followed by a `NameError` (because `last` is never defined). And you never use `self.last` at all, which seems a bit suspicious, correctness-wise.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Thanks for the catch. Fixed

Comment: returns `wrong_list_fixed = [[0, <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f03ceef6550>], ...`

Comment: Still has problems though. You `map(list,` on the result of `groupby`, but `groupby` yields pairs of values (the second element of which is the group you probably meant to listify), and listifying that `tuple` doesn't help. Simpler in this case to just use a listcomp, rather than the layers of `map` and `list` calls you'd need to make this work: `wrong_list_fixed = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(wrong_list, key())]` (or on Py3.5+, you could save the cost of looking up/calling the `list` constructor with `wrong_list_fixed = [[*g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(wrong_list, key())]`

Comment: @ShadowRanger. That's what I get for being lazy and not testing my code before posting. Fixed it up now.

Comment: It messes up when a key from key_list is repeated later in wrong_key_list.

Comment: @Harvey. Fixed that too.

Comment: @sfortney. You did ask for itertools :)

Comment: I'm torn. I like this solution more than mine, but I had to use mine (easier to code correctly the first time) to debug this one. I feel like I would have written mine in production and refactored it into this one in production.

Comment: Haha I saw that. I was hoping it would really simplify things though. The frontend effort of making the key almost exactly cancelled out the code you save using itertools. That groupby key is brilliant though!

Comment: I almost always prefer solutions that let Python internals do most of the work.

Comment: @sfortney. My original take on `key` was a function, but it required a global or mutable default parameter to hold `last`. I then beefed it up to retain `key_list` as well for completeness.

Comment: @sfortney. I think you did the right thing here. Having two good answers is not the worst that could happen :)

Answer (score 1):

I get slightly different result from yours, but give it a try. If this is not what you want, I will delete my answer.

```
idx = sorted(set([b.index(ai) for ai in a] + [len(b)]))
c = [b[i:j] for i, j in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:])]
```

Comment: `c` is missing some elements and contains some empty lists

Comment: @Harvey what about now? I just edited my answer. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: missing and empty fixed, now some lists are split in the wrong place

Comment: I added the inputs and the correct output to my answer for you to use in testing. They're all converted to letters and numbers to make debugging easier.

Comment: @Harvey Thanks again. I think I fixed it this time but there are difference with your reference answer, i.e., at `wrong_list_fixed[14]`. I am not sure this is right: `_x0` is included in `key_list` (or I mis-understood the problem)